# On the change of word order as languages develop?

Tags: syntax, historical-linguistics, language-change, word-order

While I understand the most common changes in word order, the whole SOV can go to OSV, SVO, and OVS, and so forth. But I do not exactly understand how and why word order would change. Can you explain why these changes are believed to occur, and possible give me some sources for further reading.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How common is word order change?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/931/how-common-is-word-order-change)

Comment: No, not in the slightest. I apologize.

Comment: That's a completely different question.